# how launch a new activity which is already on the stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast to receive a SMS and launch a specified activity with data of sms.

When i receive the second SMS, the activity launched is the previous with old data and i can´t show the activity with correct data.

What i can do to launch the new activity without go at stack and launch activity from stack?

Comment: Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: and in the manifest file i have to specify it? or when i create the new intent, i add to the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job when you run that activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```